# MATLAB - Efficient row-vector*Matrix*column-vector

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I'm working on a piece of software in MATLAB and I believe I've reached the limit of my knowledge when it comes to optimisation and efficiency. Here's where the expertise of the people on StackOverflow might be helpful.

Using MATLAB's profiler, I've found that the last inefficient line of code is a multiplication of the following form:

```
function [energy] = getEnergy(S,W)
  energy = -(S*W*S');
end
```

`S` is a `1`x`N` row vector, `W` is an `N`x`N` matrix (it's not just a diagonal matrix though), and `S'` is a `N`x`1` column vector, whose multiplication returns a number.

I understand that this is a primitive operation, but I was wondering whether there is any way to speed this up.

I tried searching Google etc, but unfortunately I do not know the right keywords to search for. I apologise if this is a duplicate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your profile's picture is a bit offensive. would you consider replacing it with something less disturbing?

Comment: @sudosensei Are there any special attributes to matrix `W`? For example, is it [symmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix)?

Comment: Matlab is quite efficient when it comes to matrix/vector products. Use `profiler` to spot your bottleneck more carefully.

Comment: @EitanT: Yes, actually W is symmetric.

Comment: That's exactly the line of code MATLAB's profiler highlights.

Comment: How many times do you call this function? how many `S` vectors are you trying to compute the energy for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation is correct, and the fastest.

You can save ~20-30% of computation time by performing it inside the main code, without call to the function.

```
>> S = randn(1, 500);
>> W = randn(500);
>> tic; for k = 1 : 10000, e = -(S * W * S'); end; toc
Elapsed time is 0.321595 seconds.
```

Comment: The function call was indeed the issue. Thank you, Serg.

Answer (score 0):

If the bottleneck stems from the fact that you need to repeat this computation for a LOT of different vectors `S`, then you can do the following vectorization:

```
% s is k-by-N matrix of k row vectors
energy = sum( ( s * W ) .* s, 2 ); % note the .* in the middle!
```

Comment: this does not improve the speed of `s*W*s'` operation.

Comment: @Serg if you have `k` vectors than its faster than calling `getEergy` `k` times.

Comment: @Shai: I marked Serg's answer as the accepted answer because it was more related to what I asked, but I actually combined both of your answers and my program sped up considerably. Thank you!